# TortoiseGit: how reopen rebase dialog/session

Tags: tortoisegit

how do i reopen the TortoiseGit rebase session/dialog if i accidentally closed it?

I think, that i could continue without it or with the git command line, but:
Is it possible to list the rebase steps with TortoiseGit after closing the window?

Thank you

Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseGit has its own rebase implementation which is different from the CLI one ATM (2.6.0).

When closing the dialo the process is aborted (there should be at least one message box asking for confirmation). You need to restart it.